# Need help making String toString() method

Tags: java, tostring

I'm making a program that basically shows complex numbers, both the real and imaginary parts have their own data members, and then it shows some math being done with them (add, subtract, multiply).
I have two class files, `public class Complex()` and public class `ComplexTester()`. In my `Complex()` class I have no idea what to do to the `toString()` method to get the output to look like this: http://i.gyazo.com/4fd9e08113e4668b6d4ac3678387092b.png

Here's some of the main stuff in my `Complex()` class to give you an idea of what it's doing.

```
//**********Methods to perform calculations with object**********

public Complex add(Complex c){
    return new Complex((c.realPart + this.realPart) , (c.imaginaryPart + this.imaginaryPart));
}

public Complex subtract(Complex c){
    return new Complex((this.realPart - c.realPart) , (this.imaginaryPart - c.imaginaryPart));
}

public Complex multiply(Complex c){
    return new Complex();
}  



//Checks if an object is equal to the parameter
    public boolean equals(Complex c){
        return isEqual(c.getReal(), this.getReal()) && isEqual(c.getImaginary(), this.getImaginary());
    }

    //Allows checking of equality of doubles
    public boolean isEqual(double x, double y){
        //multiplier for 8 decimal places
        final double dec = Math.pow(10, 8);

        return (Math.round((x * dec)) == Math.round(y * dec));
    }
```

And then here's the tester:

---

```
public class ComplexTester
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //Declare five objects in the Complex class
        Complex c1, c2, c3, c4, c5;

        //Initialize Complex objects using constructors
        c1 = new Complex(1.5, -0.8);
        c2 = new Complex(2,3);
        c3 = new Complex();
        c4 = new Complex(2);
        c5 = new Complex(0,7);

        //Show all four objects
        System.out.println("c1 is " + c1);
        System.out.println("c2 is " + c2);
        System.out.println("c3 is " + c3);
        System.out.println("c4 is " + c4);
        System.out.println("c5 is " + c5);
        System.out.println();

        //Determine if objects are real numbers
        System.out.println(c1 + " is " + (c1.isReal() ? "real" : "NOT real"));
        System.out.println(c4 + " is " + (c4.isReal() ? "real" : "NOT real"));
        System.out.println();

        //Manually set a value
        c3.setValue(c1.getReal(), c1.getImaginary());
        System.out.println("Changed c3 to " + c3);

        //Test for equality
        System.out.print (c1 + " is ");
        System.out.print ( (c1.equals(c3)) ? "equal" : "NOT equal");
        System.out.println (" to " + c3);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print (c1 + " is ");
        System.out.print ( (c1.equals(c2)) ? "equal" : "NOT equal");
        System.out.print (" to " + c2);
        System.out.println();


        //Demonstrate math operations
        System.out.println ("\n Some Math Operations:");
        System.out.println (c1 + " + " + c2 + " = " + c1.add(c2));
        System.out.println (c1 + " - " + c2 + " = " + c1.subtract(c2));
        System.out.println ("(" + c1 + ") * " + "(" + c2 + ") = " + c1.multiply(c2));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("This concludes the test of the Complex number class.");
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `toString` method for ouputting complex numbers of the form `a+bi`, you can use something like:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(realPart) + "+" +
           String.valueOf(imagPart) + "i";
}
```

Of course, you can get fancy and figure out whether the individual bits are missing:

```
public String toString() {
    if (imaginaryPart == 0)
        return String.valueOf(realPart);
    if (realPart == 0)
        return String.valueOf(imagPart) + "i";
    return realPart + "+" + imagPart + "i";
}
```

---

See, for example, the following test program:

```
public class Cplx {
    private double realPart, imagPart;

    public Cplx(double r, double i) {
        realPart = r;
        imagPart = i;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (imagPart == 0)
            return String.valueOf(realPart);

        if (realPart == 0)
            return String.valueOf(imagPart) + "i";

        return realPart + "+" + imagPart + "i";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cplx n;
        n = new Cplx(0,0); System.out.println(n);
        n = new Cplx(1,0); System.out.println(n);
        n = new Cplx(0,2); System.out.println(n);
        n = new Cplx(1,2); System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
0.0
1.0
2.0i
1.0+2.0i
```

Comment: Thank you so much... generally I understand when the teacher explains things in class, but she didn't really explain this too well. That, or it's just one of the more difficult concepts we've learned so far.

Answer (score 1):

toString() returns a String representation of the Object.

For instance in your Complex class you have variables for real and imaginary parts, you might have a toString() method that looks like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Complex [realPart=" + realPart + ", imaginaryPart="
            + imaginaryPart + "]";
}
```

If you are using eclipse for your Java development you can actually auto generate toString() and some other methods. Generally you wouldn't format output in a toString() method. You should make a separate display method for that.

Comment: I'm curious about your last sentence, not formatting output. Given that `toString()` is used for things like `System.out.println(myComplexVar)`, I would think that's the _exact_ pace to render it, otherwise your print statements are going to become needlessly complex.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliy for printing, you can use

```
System.out.printf("%.3f + %.3fi",1.21312939123,3.44);
```

You can change the decimal places to your requirement

On similar lines, you can form a string with real partvariable + " + " +complexpart+"i".